# C# Web Api подключение MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Пытаюсь с помощью запроса WebApi изменить что то в базе данных.
Но когда идёт запрос подключения к бд, выдаёт оишбку:

> The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception

Класс откуда идёт запрос на бд:

```
 static DB db = new DB();

    public static string sMacAddressUpdate(string sMacAddress, string NickName)
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `players` SET `Did` = @DID WHERE `players`.`name` = @NAME;", db.getConnection());

        command.Parameters.Add("@DID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sMacAddress;
        command.Parameters.Add("@NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NickName;

        db.OpenConnection();

        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            db.CloseConnection();
            return "OK";
        }
        else
        {
            db.CloseConnection();
            return "Error DB";
        }
    }
```

Класс бд:

```
public class DB
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=base");

    public void OpenConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    public MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: непонятно только зачем впрямую с помощью текстового SQL запроса что-то менять, можно же юзать Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

Помогло смена MySql.Data.dll на установку пакета "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" и использование ссылки MySqlConnector